# Size not matching in VAE

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Here is the loss function of VAE and I am kind of stuck in it. The last line is generation error as the addition cannot be done between two tensors having shape of [?,2] and [?,784] which is perfectly valid as kl_loss is between mean and std deviation of latent vector whilst reconstruction loss is binary cross entropy. T

```
   def vae_loss(original_image,reconstructed_image):
        # E P(X|Z)
        reconstruction_loss = K.sum(original_image*(K.log(reconstructed_image))+ (1-original_image)*K.log(1-reconstructed_image),axis=1)
        kl_loss = 0.5*K.sum(K.exp(log_stddev) + K.square(mean) -1 - log_stddev,axis=1)
        return kl_loss+reconstruction_loss
```

Here I am modeled latent vector given by following function

```
def create_latent_vector(args):
    mean,log_stddev = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape = (batch_size,latent_vector_dimension), mean=0,stddev = 1.0)
    return mean + K.exp(log_stddev*0.5)*epsilon
```

The batch size is 32 and latent_vector_dimension is 2. Am I missing a point here? It is definitely valid that the error of dimension occurs, but I cannot resolve. How can I match the size between the kl_loss which is of size [?, 2] and reconstruction_loss which is of size 784 ? By the way the data is mnist.

Answer (score 0):

In your `kl_loss` there is one term for each of the random variables in your latent code, simply sum by last axis to get a loss of shape `[?]` which is loss per batch element.

As far as your `reconstruction_loss` is concerned it should already be of shape `[?]` not `[?, 784]` as you are already summing along what I assume to be the flattened pixel axis.